# SVG images not showing when their size is set through ng-attr-width or ng-style?

Tags: angularjs, svg

(N.B. This is a follow-on from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28093277/575530).)

Here is some simple HTML, CSS, and AngularJS to display three pictures of bullfinches from flickr:

```
<html ng-app="AngularSVGTestApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular SVG Image Size Test</title>
    <style>
        svg {
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <div ng-cloak>
        <svg ng-show="mainCtrl.svg.show" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" baseProfile="full" version="1.1" width="200" height="400">
            <!-- https://www.flickr.com/photos/yeliseev/10116904936 -->
            <image xlink:href="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5535/10116904936_870f94488d_m.jpg"
                   x="20" y="20"
                   width="100" height="100"/>
            <!-- https://www.flickr.com/photos/yeliseev/112992806 -->
            <image xlink:href="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/38/112992806_780ebcd0ce_m.jpg"
                   x="20" y="140"
                   ng-attr-width="mainCtrl.svg.style.width"
                   ng-attr-height="mainCtrl.svg.style.height" /> 
            <!-- https://www.flickr.com/photos/yeliseev/4433515854 -->
            <image xlink:href="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4058/4433515854_41152445a9_m.jpg"
                   x="20" y="260"
                   ng-style="mainCtrl.svg.style" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('AngularSVGTestApp', [])
                .controller('MainCtrl', [function () {
                    var self = this;
                    self.svg = {
                        show: true,
                        style: {
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100
                        }
                    };
                }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/k9vbya2f/)

The three bullfinch images within the SVG differ in how their size is set.

1. Has its width and height set to 100 explicitly in the HTML
2. Has its width and height set to 100 using `ng-attr-width` and `ng-attr-height` to bind to model values held in the controller
3. Has its width and height set to 100 using `ng-style` to bind to model values held in the controller

Why don't either of these latter two methods work? What should I use to bind the dimensions of an image in an SVG from AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like, here is the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings)

```
 ng-attr-width="{{mainCtrl.svg.style.width}}"
 ng-attr-height="{{mainCtrl.svg.style.height}}"
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9vbya2f/1/)

as for ngStyle

here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552952/is-it-possible-to-change-svg-included-as-img-element-styles-from-external-cs) . In short, I don't think you can do that with ngStyle.

Here is some [ref](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html). It shows you how to do it in CSS correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I find it confusing that `ng-show="mainCtrl.svg.show"` works without the double curlies but `ng-attr-width="mainCtrl.svg.style.width"` does not

Comment: Can you explain why the double curlies are needed for `ng-attr-width` and `ng-attr-height` but not for `ng-show`?

Comment: You need to read about the doc for [directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-). In short, it is just a different way to bind with directive scope. It really depends on the way you create the directive.